# Output failing URL when using Axios

Tags: javascript, axios, nightwatch

I'm using [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) and [alasql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alasql) npm packages with **nightwatchjs** to test a list of URLs (from a spreadsheet).

The test works as I'd hoped, in that the webpage is loaded, and the subsequent HTML checked to ensure that `Bauer.Golf.CourseCountry.Search` is not present within the page HTML.

My code is below;

```
var alasql = require('alasql');
var axios = require('axios');

module.exports = {
    '@tags': ['priorityDesktopTest','priorityMobileTest','stagingDesktopTest','stagingMobileTest'],
    'Sitemap test for TG pages': async (browser) => {
        var result = await alasql.promise('select URL from xlsx("./testUrls.xlsx",{sheetid:"Sheet2"})');
        var xcelData = result.map(item => {
            return item.URL;
        });
        async function siteMapUrlsTestArr(item) {
            axios.get(browser.launch_url + item)
            .then(html => {
                const pageInfo = html.data;
                browser.verify.equal((pageInfo.includes("Bauer.Golf.CourseCountry.Search")), false);
            });
        }
        for (let index = 0; index < 2500; index++) {
            var xmlTestUrl = xcelData[Math.floor(Math.random()*xcelData.length)];
            await siteMapUrlsTestArr(xmlTestUrl);
        }
    },
};
```

But at the moment, if there's an error in one of the URLs, then the output only displays;

> ✖ NightwatchAssertError
> Failed [equal]: (true == false) - expected "false" but got: "true" (2ms)

```
Error location:
/Users/darrenharley/Documents/Git/uk-content-todaysgolfer/Tests/Functional/priorityTests/QA-633-sitemap.js:21
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
 19 |             .then(html => {
 20 |                 const pageInfo = html.data;
 21 |                 browser.verify.equal((pageInfo.includes("Bauer.Golf.CourseCountry.Search")), false); 
 22 |             });
 23 |         }
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

But what I'd like to do is also specifically display the failing URL, so I can debug this, rather than the generic output I currently get.

However, I'll be testing 2500 URLs so only want the *failing* URL displayed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.